# SQLite iOS, does not perform INSERT. No error message. result = SQLITE_OK = 0

Tags: ios, sqlite, sql-insert

I am trying to do INSERT, the same way as i did it for logging in. I get no error message, everything seems fine, but finally when i check database, there is not new record. when I check output of `int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insert, NULL); - result is 0. SQLITE_OK equals 0 as well.

The code:
Method addArticle: ...

```
- (BOOL)addArticle:(NSString *)Content
                author:(NSString *)Author
                  date:(NSString *)Date
                   url:(NSString *)Url
                  tags:(NSString*)Tags
               arhived:(NSInteger)Archived
                 title:(NSString *)Title
{
    NSString *sql = @"INSERT INTO Article (content,author,date,url,tags,archived, title)"
    " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *insert;
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, [sql UTF8String], -1, &insert, NULL);
    if (result == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"Article was added. %d %d", result, SQLITE_OK);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 1, [Content UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 2, [Author UTF8String],  -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 3, [Date UTF8String],     -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 4, [Url UTF8String],     -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 5, [Tags UTF8String],     -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int (insert, 6, (NSInteger)Archived);
        sqlite3_bind_text(insert, 7, [Title UTF8String],   -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        result = sqlite3_step(insert);
        return true;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error: insert prepare statement failed: %s.", sqlite3_errmsg(self.db));
        return false;
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(insert);
}
```

`And this is where I use it:

It is in InboxViewController, I get data from web as json and save it. I have checked, all json data is correct and received.

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    if(sizeof(response)>0){
        NSLog(@"Got response from server %@", response);
        NSError* error;
        NSArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:response //1
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&error];
        self.jsonData = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:json];
        int count = 0;
        NSLog(@"Size of received data %d", self.jsonData.count);
        for (int i=0; i<self.jsonData.count; i++) {

            NSDictionary *item = [self.jsonData objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString* content = [item objectForKey:@"content"];
            NSString* author = [item objectForKey:@"author"];
            NSString* date = [item objectForKey:@"date"];
            NSString* url = [item objectForKey:@"url"];
            NSString* tags = [item objectForKey:@"tags"];
            NSInteger archived = [[item objectForKey:@"archived"]integerValue];
            NSString* title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %ld %@ ", content, author, date, url, tags, (long)archived, title);
            [self.db openDatabase];
            BOOL added = [self.db addArticle:content author:author date:date url:url tags:tags arhived:archived title:title];
            [self.db closeDatabase];
            count++;
            if (added == true) {
                NSLog(@"articles has been added. True? %hhd", added);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Failed to add article ");
            }
        }
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Did not get resopnse from server: %@", response);
    }
    connection = nil;
}
```

So, why this does not work? Thank you.

Comment: What is being output when it fails? Could you possibly put a log statement before you submit to see if the insert statement looks correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I have put Log statements, but I don't get any error message.And I cannot see if it fails or not, it looks like everything worked, but actually, no record inserted. I also tried the query to run in  Terminal, and it works.

Comment: What's the value of `result` after calling `sqlite3_step`?

Comment: Why do you open and close the database for each insert? That's silly. Open the database at the start of the app and close it at the end.

Comment: @rmaddy, after calling sqlite3_step , result equals to 5. I think that keeping database connection opened till app is closed, is not good, is it? The app is something like Pocket.

Comment: I have a very complex, multi-threaded database app and I use a single database connection open for the entire lifetime of the app. Not a problem. A result of 5 is `SQLITE_BUSY`. Your database is locked so the insert is failing. FYI - you have lots of error checking but you didn't bother adding any error checking on the most important function call - `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: @rmaddy, thank you for that suggestion, ill manage connection to db in that way now. I will try to figure out why database is locked and report result here.

Comment: At least for now, open the database before the loop and close it after the loop. That alone would be a big improvement. Look around the rest of your code and see if you can find mismatches to calls to open/close, prepare/finalize.

Comment: @rmaddy , you were right about finalising, I suppose, it was because i finalised a statement after return statement. I have moved those, and now it works. Thank you, you rock! )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be because of misplaced sqlite3_finalize(select); statement. I put it after return statement in a method. This caused database to be busy.